# Spring Hibernate - Dao Return By Id

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao

I use Spring & Hibernate and i would like to get a product with his id in my DAO.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 

@Autowired 
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<Product> getProductList() {

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Product p order by p.productName asc").list();
}  

public Product getProductById(int productId) {

    String hql = "from Product p where p.productId = :id";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setInteger("id", productId);

    return null;
    }
}
```

For example when i would like to get all my products i return list of them  (calling function getProductList() ), but now i want to call getProductById but i don't know how i could return something with the "Product" type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your getProductById(int productId) method:

```
return (Product) query.uniqueResult();
```